# Submit a form that contain a textarea using AJAX

Tags: jquery

I can't submit a form using AJAX , the problem exist just when i include a textarea in the from , when i delete it, the form submit correctly .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        var formData = {
            'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'cont'          : $('input[name=cont]').val(),
            'date'  : $('input[name=date]').val(),
            'prix'              : $('input[name=prix]').val(),
            'timestart'             : $('input[name=timestart]').val(),
            'nbm'   : $('input[name=nbm]').val()             
        };
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', 
            url         : 'zzz.php',
            data        : formData,
            dataType    : 'json' 
        }) ........
```

Comment: There's something called [$('form').serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: @adeneo how can i use it here . in my example.

Comment: Which is the text area?  Can you post the html form too?

Comment: @Will it's a simple form <textarea  name="cont" placeholder="your msg"></textarea>

Comment: And what happens when you submit the form?  Is the data corrupted? missing?

Comment: where did you get placeholder="your msg"? I didn't know textarea had a property of placeholder. Normally the text goes inside of the start and end tags.

Comment: i foud the answer , i just instead of using '$('input[name=cont]').val(),' i use '$("#conttt").val(),'  thanks all of you guys .

Comment: then add your answer and make it accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032184/submit-a-form-that-contain-a-textarea-using-ajax/23032570#comment-35187108) your `textarea` has a `name="cont"` attribute:

```
<textarea name="cont" placeholder="your msg"></textarea>
```

But to get the reference to this `textarea` element you are using `input[name=cont]` selector which selects any `input` element with `name="cont"` attribute but not a `textarea` element.

To select the `textarea` you should use:

```
$('textarea[name=cont]')
```

Answer (score 0):

please use jut a single line of code

```
$("#formid").serialize();
```

instead of

```
    var formData = {`enter code here`
                'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
                'cont'          : $('input[name=cont]').val(),
                'date'  : $('input[name=date]').val(),
                'prix'              : $('input[name=prix]').val(),
                'timestart'             : $('input[name=timestart]').val(),
                'nbm'   : $('input[name=nbm]').val()             
            };
```

and then try to submit